# OWF and iO Correlation

Tags: one-way-function, io

What is the relationship between one way functions(OWF) and indistinguishable obfuscation(iO)? I know that iO exists even when P=NP and OWF don't exist. But does the existence of OWF imply iO?

Comment: Note that iO still "morally" implies OWF: if NP is not contained in (infinitely often) BPP, then iO implies OWF - see [here](https://eprint.iacr.org/2014/347.pdf).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We don't know of any construction of iO from one-way functions[*], and it would be highly surprising if such a thing existed. Indeed, [iO + OWF implies public-key encryption](https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/454) (and various other “cryptomania” primitives), so if OWF alone implied iO, it would also imply PKE.

[*] <s>At this point in time, we don't know of any construction of iO from standard assumptions, period, as far as I know</s> (see Geoffroy's comment below).

Comment: I guess we don't know how to build PKE from OWF?

Comment: Yes, and I we have good reasons to think that such a construction shouldn't exist. For example, a *black-box* construction is known to be impossible, and even some classes of non-black-box constructions have been ruled out. See e.g. this reply: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/83929/1423

Comment: "At this point in time, we don't know of any construction of iO from standard assumptions, period, as far as I know"

I disagree, we now have constructions of iO from perfectly fine assumptions: subexponential LPN over large fields + subexponential hardness of Goldreich PRG + subexponential SXDH. All are old, well studied, highly plausible assumptions that I would call standard.

Comment: Fair enough, I haven't followed all the recent results!